# Why Permission Denied with NFS after reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, freebsd, nfs

I have Ubuntu and CentOS clients nfsv3 mounting to a FreeBSD box, which got rebooted while the nfs clients were connected. Now the clients get a permission denied when they try to access the mount points.

On the client I have tried

```
# umount /nobackup/dat
umount.nfs: /nobackup/dat: device is busy
umount.nfs: /nobackup/dat: device is busy

# fuser /nobackup/dat
Cannot stat file /proc/1660/fd/473: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/1660/fd/475: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/1660/fd/476: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/1660/fd/478: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/1660/fd/479: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/14509/fd/1: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/14674/fd/1: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/14871/fd/1: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/27872/fd/436: Stale NFS file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/27872/fd/444: No such file or directory

# umount -f /nobackup/dat
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount.nfs: /nobackup/dat: device is busy
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount.nfs: /nobackup/dat: device is busy
```

**Update**

Now I have killed all the processes and successfully unmounted `/nobackup/dat`, but I still get the permission denied error for some reason.

```
# fuser -m /nobackup/dat 2>&1 | awk -F'/' '{print $3}' | xargs -n 1 kill
# fuser -m /nobackup/dat
# umount -l /nobackup/dat
# ll /nobackup/dat
ls: cannot open directory /nobackup/dat: Permission denied

# mount /nobackup/dat
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null)
```

**Question**

Any suggestions how to debug this?

Comment: I'd start by unmounting and remounting the nfs shares.

Comment: @JennyD Good point. Ihave updated the OP, as this gives me a "Stale NFS file handle".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the clients didn't realise that the nfs server went away, so they're still trying to access the filehandle that was originally created the previous time they mounted the file system.

Normally, rebooting the client is a sure way of making it remount the file systems. But if you don't want to do that, start by killing all processes that are trying to use the NFS file systems. After that, you can try a "lazy umount" with

```
umount -l
```

You might also try to remount the filesystem, using

```
mount -o remount
```

Otherwise, the old file handles *will* timeout at some point, though I don't know how long it will take.

Once you've successfully gotten rid of the stale filehandles, remount the filesystems:

```
mount nobackup/dat
```

Comment: Very nice. I have killed the processes, but still get permission denied. See updated OP. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You need to also mount the file systems again

Comment: Updated the OP when trying to mount it again.

Comment: Check the export rules on the server. You may need to restart the NFS daemon on the server.