# NFS mount point is not being accessible after stopping NFS service

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, rhel6

I have shared a directory on my NFS server to another machine. I am successfully mounting the NFS Share and able to access.

After few days, I was supposed to stop the NFS service on the NFS server due to server maintenance. But unfortunately I did not unmount the NFS mount point on the NFS client.

Now, keeping NFS mount point in unmounted state, if I try to access the mount point as a local directory of NFS client, I could not access it and in fact the machine is hanging and I need to open a new session.

I even checked by starting the NFS service on the NFS server and even tried to mount from the client machine, but still the same issue persists.

Please help me in urgent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of this search [stale nfs handle](http://serverfault.com/search?q=stale+nfs+handle). This question ha been asked before and already has answers on Server Fault.

Comment: If Ed is right then it's an actual dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/561642/why-permission-denied-with-nfs-after-reboot

Comment: I have a small concern before marking it as a duplicate. I am not getting an error related to "stale nfs handle" at all. But anyways the link suggested by lain gave me a clue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I could resolve the issue. Earlier I used the below command for mounting NFS share through which I did not understand anything moreover it is taking long time with out any error throwing.

The command I ran earlier was below.

```
# mount -t nfs <nfs server ip>:/<nfs share> <mount point>
```

But I could not understand what the problem is through this. Later I ran the below command enabling the verbosity.

```
# mount -v -t nfs <nfs server ip>:/<nfs share> <mount point>
```

Now it displayed that the  to which I am trying to mount is `already in use or busy`.

Then I ran the below command for unmounting the

```
# umount <mount point>
```

Now, I retried to mount with the above mount command which gave me successful output.

Answer (score 0):

Run a lazy unmount of the mount. This is accomplished with `umount -l /mountpoint` - That will work until you resolve your other issues.